# Phaser 3 How to run a spritesheet animation AND move

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have a spritesheet for the "player". As you press the arrow keys, it moves around. However, I can only get it to run the animation AFTER moving, or something similar where you can only move OR run the animation. I need it to move AND run the animation. Here is the relevant code so far-

```
var cursors;
var player;
class Scene1 extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super("bootGame");
  }
  preload() {
    this.load.spritesheet(
    "player",
    "https://cdn.glitch.com/34a2793c-cdda-4b47-b469-f0357b9fc0f1%2FAH_SpriteSheet_People2.png? 
    v=1595522143234",
      { frameWidth: 16, frameHeight: 16 }
    );
  }
  create() {        
    player = this.add.sprite(30, 30, "player");
    this.anims.create({
      key: "left",
      frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers("player", { start: 12, end: 14 }),
      frameRate: 10,
      repeat: 1
    });
    cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    update() {
      if (cursors.left.isDown) {
        player.anims.play("left");
        player.x -= 1;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Also a great place to get help is the https://phaser.discourse.group/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: (the second parameter is for `ignoreIfPlaying`)

```
player.anims.play("left",true);
```

I think what is happening is the default of false for the second parameter is restarting the animation. This will make it look like it isn't playing because it only completes after you release the left key.
the `true` will allow it to play through before it tries to restart it (while holding the left)